# The proportion of twitter followers of handle X also following Y

Tags: r, twitter, probability, shared

OK, someone recently asked me what the probability that followers of Twitter handle X are also followers of Twitter handle Y. I used some R code (using the twitteR package) to get 47,000 followers from X and 61,000 followers of Y (the two handles have a LOT of followers). I created a vector and found that roughly 1200 data points were repeats (so 600 followers came up twice). My question now is, how do I find the proportion of shared followers. This is my reasoning:

```
p(A and B) = p(B)*p(A)
```

where the `p(A and B)` = probability of sampling someone who follows X and Y pages two times (once when sampling for X and once for the Y) = 1200/(61000+46000) = 1200/108000 = 0.011

```
p(A) = probability of sampling an X follower who also follows the Y

p(B) = the probability of sampling an Y follower who also follows the X
```

I am going to assume that `p(A) = p(B)`.

so we can substitute 0.011 for `p(A and B)` and `p(A)` for `p(B)` to get:

```
0.011 = p(B)*p(B)

0.011 = p(B)^2

.104 = p(B) = p(A)
```

So, roughly 10% of X's followers also follow Y's. Am I correct in this line of reasoning? Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: p(A and B) = p(B)*p(A) holds if and only if A is independent from B. Which you hope is not the case here.

Comment: Why would I hope that the cases are not independent? If I sample followers from twitter handle X, that sampling should be independent from when I sample from Y, right?

Answer (score 0):

Well you should ask this question in a maths forum this one focus on programming.

The formula you are looking for is : 
P(Y given X) = P(Y and X)/P(X)

47,000 follow X, 61,000 follow Y and 600 follow both.

It means that there is a proportion 600 / 47,000  = 6 / 47 ~ 1/8 = 12.5% of followers of X that also follows Y.

That's a possible estimator of the probability that a person follows Y given that they follow X. But it does not imply anything. You have to statistically test if this proportion is high enough in your context to eventually draw any conclusion. I would imagine that 2 totally unrelated VIPs and  have thousand of common followers that just happen through a purely random process.

Comment: Yes, so 600/47000 = 0.0125, not 0.125. The problem with just relying on that proportion is that you may be sampling followers of both in the 47000 number that don't show up in the 61,000 number, right? For example follower John Doe may have been sampled only in the data retrieved from twitter handle X, but not from twitter handle Y even though John Doe follows both.